# What is the opposite of using something judiciously?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, antonyms

I want to tell a colleague to use a particular file wherever possible. Basically the opposite of using it judiciously. I ended up saying "use the file at will" — but it got me wondering if there is a one-word antonym for *judiciously*. Google suggests *foolishly* or *carelessly*, but that's not what I want to convey.

Comment: Why not just say 'use the file wherever possible',  like you meant.

Comment: @tchrist: except that means something like "foolishly" or "carelessly", which is not the meaning the OP is after.

Comment: You're confusing us because your use of *judicious* is faulty. "Wherever possible" calls on your colleague to act *judiciously* just as much as "as little as possible" or "only when necessary" would: he or she must judge whether use is "possible" or "necessary" in each situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about: "use the file [liberally](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liberally)"?

Answer (score 7):

I would say the opposite of *judiciously* can be *freely*.

Comment: This answer can be improved by adding a citation.

Answer (score 4):

*Judicious* (and the adverb's meaning parallels closely - contrast say a scheming person and a scheme of work) is defined primarily as well-considered, wise. (*having, exhibiting or proceeding from good judgment* - freedictionary)

It also allows of the near-synonym *prudent*, which has the sense

not (1) but (2) (autoformat naughty here). *Careful in regard to one's own interests; provident.* (AHDEL)

The antonyms referring to the *wise* sense are **injudicious** (general) and **capricious** or even **cavalier** (silly or callous behaviour) while an example of an antonym for the *prudent* sense is **prodigal**.

To convey the sense 'Don't feel restricted in how much you can use the file' here, which isn't a diametric opposite, the suggestions already given work well, except for *Use it liberally* which **is** the diametric opposite of *Use it sparingly*; the single-word version for the 'you decide exactly how much to use it' sense is '(You may) use it **freely**.'

Comment: +1 I definitely think *freely* is the most appropriate word for OP's context, but I like the fact that your answer goes into detail about why it's not really an "antonym" of *judiciously* in general. It just so happens OP's context skews the meaning of *judiciously* towards *infrequently* rather than *without exercising careful judgement*.

Comment: I can't make sense of "(autoformat naughty here)". It's apparent that your post needs some editing/formatting, but without understanding what the heck is going on in that paragraph, I can't fix it.

Comment: Hello, Martha. I tried to cut-and-paste: (2) _Careful in regard to one's own interests; provident._ (AHDEL) but the (2) was adjusted to (1). This happened on my second attempt also. I felt it was important to show that this was the second polyseme the AHDEL listed and not the first. And I did not wish to be outsmarted by a machine.

Comment: Hello, @Martha. I don't think the problem (trying to quote bullet point 3 say rather than 1 in an article) has been addressed yet.

Answer (score 2):

From the context, it would seem that you are looking for an antonym to ***[sparing](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/sparing)ly***, not *[judicious](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/judicious)ly*.

Say,

> "Go ahead, use it ***[generous](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/generous)ly***."

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest thing to say would be, “*Use the file whenever you want*.” However,  it sounds like you're trying to encourage the file's use more than that vanilla statement might convey.

Another way might be, “*Feel free to make heavy use of the file*,” which hints at the fact that you'd like to see the file heavily used.

If that's not sufficiently persuasive, you could try, “*Feel free to use the file with abandon*.”

Collins defines *abandon* as “unrestrained freedom of action,” and the word usually implies some sort of indulgence.

Answer (score 1):

I am a [profligate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/profligate) user of certain files myself. I use them with wild abandon; sometimes with no provocation whatsoever.

Comment: I don't think this is quite the word the OP is looking for, but +1 anyway for making me laugh. :)

Comment: -1 Sadly, that's **not** what the OP means to say, though he (rather incorrectly) uses the word *judiciously*. I'm sure he is not asking people to use it carelessly.

Answer (score 0):

I like the term *promiscuously*. [Merriam-Webster's](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promiscuous) 2nd definition states:

> not restricted to one class, sort, or person : indiscriminate: *education … cheapened through the promiscuous distribution of diplomas* — Norman Cousins

It connotes a feeling of abandon, and the *double entendre* adds a charm.

Answer (score 0):

*Indiscriminately*, since no-one else has explicitly suggested it. To me, *injudiciously*, although it is technically a more exact antonym, suggests the conscious application of poor judgement, whereas *indiscriminately* suggests that judgement should not be exercised at all, making it a better fit for what you're trying to say.

Comment: Sadly, that's **not** what the OP means to say, though he (rather incorrectly) uses the word *judiciously*. I'm he is not asking people to use it carelessly.